# What's the difference between Destroy() and DestroyImmediate()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What's the difference between MonoBehaviour's `Destroy ()` and `DestroyImmediate ()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: in play mode, use `Destroy`. If you are creating an editor tool and need to destroy an object in edit mode, use `DestroyImmediate`. The difference is stated below:

As stated in [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), `Destroy`

> destroys an object immediately after the current `Update` loop, or X seconds from "now" if a time is specified.

This ensures during the Update loop you will be able to do what you have to do with the object without getting reference errors. Think about many MonoBehaviour pointing to an object, and one of them decides to destroy the object, the benefit of the `Destroy` is that the object is not immediately destroyed. As soon as the Update loop ends, the object will be destroyed and any further access to its resources in next frames will throw an exception.

Again, according to [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html), `DestroyImmediate`

> destroys the object object immediately. You are strongly recommended to use Destroy instead.
> This function should only be used when writing editor code since the delayed destruction will never be invoked in edit mode

Occurs that in the edit mode, when you are creating a tool for Unity itself, calling `Destroy` will not work because of the lifecycle in the editor. So you need to Destroy the object Immediately and stop accessing it.